# Drawing line through UITableView cells

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6

Is it possible to draw a line with different width through some cells in **UITableView**?
Something like this:
[image: table view]
I'm using Xcode 4.6 and target is iOS5+

Comment: Are you referring to a strikethrough on the text?

Comment: @jsksma2 no, a line with custom pen. exactly like the picture

Comment: Be more specfic. When you say "custom", are asking that the user literally draws the strikethrough, or do you just want it to appear?

Comment: @jsksma2 no user does not draws the line. The app will draw lines. Imagine this a list of tasks, and lines drawn on expired tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough idea on how it might work.  You'll need to manage the red line when the reusable cell content changes.

```
CGSize size = [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.textLabel.font];
CGFloat y = cell.contentView.frame.size.height / 2;

UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,y,size.width, 3)];
line.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cell.textLabel addSubview:line];
```

Answer (score 0):

make some lines(like image, etc) above the tableViewCell

like [cell.contentView addSubView:$LINE_IMAGE_VIEW]

you can get the label's width like this

```
CGFloat width = cell.titleLabel.frame.size.width
```

then assign that width to custom line image.

Answer (score 0):

This will strike through the whole cell. In case you need it to look like completed task:

```
CGSize size = cell.contentView.frame.size; // you'll draw the line in whole cell.

        UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,size.height / 2,size.width - 30, 1)];
        line.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; // set your preferred color
        [cell addSubview:line];
```

You may indicate some other value in CGRectMake instead of 15 - it's offset by X. In this case you'd better then decrease width by doubled value (in my case it's 15*2 = 30) in order it look nice.